# Upgrading Magento from 1.1.8 to 1.5 stable

Tags: magento, upgrade, magento-1.5

Am looking to upgrade Mangeto from version 1.1.8 to version 1.5.

This is a quite a leap I am taking I know, but and I have tried the following already (as some one else had suggested on another site):

- dump v1.1.8 database, restore it in a new database.
- install magento 1.5 pointing on the restored v1.1.8 database
- let the upgrader run
- add the old theme files
- test that it all works.

When doing that, the upgrader kept saying some tables already existed.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: what tables is it complaining about?

Comment: don't worry i've got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fine now, basically make sure you're using the same server environment.